# Azure Function with MessageReceiver and .NET 5?

Tags: azure

I'm having problems trying to inject a MessageReceiver instance into my .NET 5 function like this:

```
[Function("MyFunction")
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "sbconn")] 
    MyMessage myMessage, FunctionContext context, MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
```

The error is:

> Exception:
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Diagnostics.Exceptions.FunctionInputConverterException:
> Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'MyFunction': Cannot
> convert input parameter 'messageReceiver' to type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver' from type
> 'System.String'.

I have tried re-arranging the signature using various positions of messageReceiver but nothing works.

Also tried adding a string param where the runtime expects it to be as per the message above.. didn't work, error message still the same.

Has anybody managed to inject/resolve an instance of MessageReceiver with .NET 5 Functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMessageReceiver is no longer bindable with dotnet-isolated in .Net 5. See here [IMessageReceiver on ServiceBusTrigge](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/293)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the link, instead of appending it via a comment.